# Add loading indicator to fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add loading spins [like this](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/) to fullcalendar, when I'm changing months in it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 26):

Fullcalendar V1: You should make use of `loading` function Triggered when event fetching starts/stops.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        loading: function( isLoading, view ) {
            if(isLoading) {// isLoading gives boolean value
                //show your loader here 
            } else {
                //hide your loader here
            }
        }
});
```

Fullcalendar V2: When the [scheduler](https://fullcalendar.io/Scheduler/) plugin is loaded, this callback is also fired when resources are fetched.

Answer (score 9):

You can easily do this using available fullcalendar methods.

[loading](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/loading/) - triggers when events fetching starts

[eventAfterAllRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/) - Triggered after all events have finished rendering.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    loading: function (bool) {
       alert('events are being rendered'); // Add your script to show loading
    },
    eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
        alert('all events are rendered'); // remove your loading 
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

FullCalendar Version v4 & v5 has a "Loading" callback here is a basic example:

Here is the link to the documentation: [FullCalendar (Loading..)](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/loading)

Styles Example:

```
     #loading {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 120px;
        left: 470px;
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
        opacity: 0.7;
        background-color: #fff;
        z-index: 99;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #loading-image {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 240px;
        z-index: 100;
    }
```

HTML Where Calendar Output, Add DIV that will overlay and link to progress gif image of your choice:

```
<div id="calendar"></div> <div id="loading" style="display:none;">
<img id="loading-image" src="/img/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>
```

By default style display:none the loading div will be hidden. By using the callback to trigger the show/hide of this progress bar. So the load start event (true) will show the div layer and when it returns (false) indicating not loading anymore, it will hide the div layer.

```
 var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  loading: function (isLoading) {
                    if (isLoading) {
                        $('#loading').show();
                    }
                    else {                
                        $('#loading').hide();
                    }
                }
  //add rest of your calendar events/options        
 });
```

Comment: Does the loading function get called when you use eventSource array of api links? I have tried and successfully get the information and event https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSourceSuccess is called but loading function is never called